# PHP - Laravel: conditionally extend blade template with ternary operator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to compose my blades in such a way that i don't a lot of logic in them. Therefore i need to check some variables before deciding which template that should be extended.

The problem is that layouts.identified is always extended no matter if $user is set or not. This results in this error: Trying to get property of non-object, because it tries to access the $user object which is not always there.

There are zero other errors so i guess the syntax is ok.

What am i doing wrong here?

```
@extends(isset($user) ? 'layouts.identified' : 'layouts.anonymous', [
    'a' => $a,
    'b' => $b,
    'c' => $c,
    'd' => $d,
    'e' => $e,
]);
```

EDIT: typo

Comment: use `isset($user)&&count($user)>0`

Comment: Try `@extends(((isset($user)) ? 'layouts.identified' : 'layouts.anonymous'), [..]);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of variable you can use Auth Facade -

```
@extends(\Auth::check() ? 'layouts.identified' : 'layouts.anonymous' , ['a' => $a, 'b' => $b,'c' => $c,'d' => $d,'e' => $e])
```

please check if error persist.

Comment: Thanks! But it's not actually possible to use the auth facade in this case, because the $user variable actually contains something else....

Comment: do u always send $user variable to view